# How Does OS X Implement backtrace()?

Tags: macos, system, backtrace

Does anyone know where I might find the code that implements OS X's version of `backtrace()`?  I know it's probably somewhere inside `libSystem.B.dylib`, so I should probably get that module's source code from [Apple's read-only open-source repository](http://opensource.apple.com/sources/), but where inside it should I start looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, most of this stuff is in [Libc](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/). In particular, `backtrace()` is defined [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/gen/backtrace.c). However, that's mostly just a thin wrapper around the internal function `_thread_stack_pcs()`, which is defined [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/gen/thread_stack_pcs.c).

The easiest way to find this sort of stuff is perhaps Google. For example, searching for `"backtrace" site:opensource.apple.com` leads you to an older version of Libc. Then, you can start from the top of http://opensource.apple.com to find the version that's used in a given version of the OS.

Comment: Huh…I thought that `libc` was inside of `LibSystem`.  Go figure!

Answer (score 2):

`backtrace()` http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/gen/backtrace.c

`_thread_stack_pcs()` http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/gen/thread_stack_pcs.c